# getting wrong date of google calendar event

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have strange issue facing with google calendar, I am fetching google calendar event in my application using oauth, this all are work perfect but the problem is if I create the event as quick add through for today or any date like

2012-02-23 today event then at fetch time in xml as response I am getting that event as for 2 two days that is the start date and end date was 2012-02-23 and 2012-02-24

like this

```
<ns1:when endTime="2012-02-26" startTime="2012-02-25">
```

while I have create new event from create button the it will given me perfect date

this is for single event created from create new

```
<ns1:when endTime="2012-02-23T12:30:00.000+05:30" startTime="2012-02-23T11:30:00.000+05:30">
```

also in google calendar show me the single date event for quick add event what the reason for this to getting wrong end date? how the google prefer this date and maintain

Comment: ns1:when is not coming up as an item in the when I try and access the field through the python library...